# What is chord Dm5b

Tags: chords

I have some notes in c minor, with chord notations. One of the chords is written as "Dm5b" and I'm wondering what that chord is. My logic would suggest d minor with the fifth lowered by a half note, but that would be D dim, and clearly there are such chords in the notes written as "H0" for example (this is a Hungarian note, and we use the German style notation, writing B as H).

Edit: attached the note.

[image]

Comment: How professional is the notation? It may just be a misspelling of Dm7b5 or Ddim.

Comment: It seems to be a scan of a printed note. Clearly not handwritten or sg like that.

Comment: If you can add a picture of the scan it might help someone pick up any other clues...

Comment: Would s and is be flat and sharp? If so, why not use the normal signs?  One gets used in the chord in question.

Comment: It seems pretty clear even from the missed second chord on the first measure that the chords were only given secondary, passing consideration here.  Unfortunately, that seems to be the norm on many published works, and errors and typos abound above the staff line, even on professionally produced scores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reckon it's a misprint, and should be Dm7b5. The dots indicate F, D, Ab and C. The rest of the run fits too, apart from the passing Eb. Dm5b isn't common (in UK at least), and had it merely been D F Ab, yes it should be Do.

Comment: Interesting -- I never heard of printed notes described as "dots."  is that common in your regions?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - you should read my answers more! Yes, on Mars, it's the accepted way to refer to them. In U.K. too ! isn't that what a lot of them resemble? Possibly not as appropriate in U.S. English - may sound like 'darts'?

Comment: I just call them "notes," since that's what they are :-) .

Comment: interesting idea, that would make playing music the same as connecting the dots.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - 'notes' are what I've written at the side of the music - conductor directions, changes in dynamics, etc...

Comment: @Tim  'Because you  know sometimes words have two meanings"   :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I am aware, and I can't think what the word is - for them! However, my way, I get to use different words. I'm happy that way. Homonym sounds about right.

Comment: @Tim - You missed the cultural reference :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I did, and still am missing . I'm not usually too thick - just help them out when they're short. Enlighten me, please!

Comment: @tim  Stairway to Heaven

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I've looked upwards for a while, and still not got it...

Comment: @Tim   Led Zeppelin?  You never heard of them?  Or just trying to see how far you can fool me ?   :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  I'm having a bad day. 'Course I know L.Z.  and Stairway to Heaven. What I've missed is the relevance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77331/discussion-between-carl-witthoft-and-tim).

Comment: isn't that like half-diminished D chord?

Answer (score -2):

Dm5b would contain D, F, Ab

b means a - so it would mean a m5-

Comment: It does contain those notes. It also, in the dots, contains enough others to produce Dm7b5. A b sometimes may mean -, but that doesn't answer the question. And more usually, it's written Do, which could translate into Dmb5, meaninglessly. And, if you'd spotted the C note, it then becomes Dm7b5. -1.